# how to include two index value test condition in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

How to include two index value test condition in a for loop?

i wish to parse a string for array syntax( find positions of '[' and ']' respectively )

```
string arrangements="a[1]";
```

so i am trying to do in one for loop for time complexity purpose.
I tried

```
for(int i=0; i<arrangements.size();i++){

if(arranements[i]=='['){
        cout<<"square opening is at : "<<i<<endl;

  while(arrangements[i]==']' ){

  cout<<"square closing is at : "<<i<<endl;
           i++;
        }
}
}
```

I even tried

```
for(int i=0; i<arrangements.size();i++){


  while(arrangements[i]==']' && arrangements[i]=='['){

  cout<<"square closing is at : "<<i<<endl;
           i++;
        }
}
}
```

sorry i am not in touch with anyone so thank you for help good peoples.

Comment: `while(arrangements[i]==']'){` => `while(arrangements[i]!=']'){`

Comment: I'd suggest researching how to write a proper recursive decent parser *or* how to write a BNF grammar for whatever you are trying to parse and then use something like bison to generate the parser from the grammar. Or, in trivial situations, use a regular expression.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thank you for these keyword, i could go to specific point now..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if...else if` or `switch`

there is case with `if...else if`:

```
const int size = arrangements.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  const char a = arrangements[i];
  if(a == '[')
    cout << "square opening is at : " << i << endl;
  else if(a == ']')
    cout << "square closing is at : " << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: thankyou, doesn't next if condition starts loop over again. can we go there after once we find the '[', for complexity purposes?

Comment: @bikashamit, what do you mean?

Comment: can we do some thing like searching of next ']' would go after the index once we have found the '[', i suspect loop for another if condition starts all over again, i could be wrong i am begineer.

Comment: loop doesn't start again for another if. It depends of `i` which incremented only after every step

Answer (score 0):

You might use `find`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != arrangements.size(); ++i) {
    if (arranements[i] == '[') {
        std::cout << "square opening is at : " << i << std::endl;
        auto e = arrangements.find(']', i + 1);
        if (e != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "square closing is at : " << e << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: sir could i use some simple i am a beginner, i don't wish to use lib function,

Comment: It is a method of `std::string`, class that you already use. If you don't want to use it, I suggest to reimplement it.